# Elasticsearch: Get sort index of the record

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Let me describe my scenario with the real example.
I have a page where I need to show the list of the companies sorted by a field "overallRank" and with few filters (like companyType and employeeSize).
Now, it's easy to get the results from the ES index for the filter and then sort them by overallRank. But, I also want to know the rank of the company among all the company data and not only in the filtered result.
For example. Amazon is the 3rd company in the location US and companyType=Private. But, it is the 5th company in the US if we remove the companyType filter. While showing the result with the filter companyType I want to know this overall ranking (i.e 5th). Is it possible to include this field in the result somehow?

What I am currently doing is first getting the filtered result by companyType and location US. Then getting the sorted result by only location. This second query gives the result by overall ranking in the location (where Amazon is coming at 5th place). Now I iterate the first result and see where that company is in the second result to determine it's overall ranking.
The problem with this approach is that second method to determine the overall ranking in the whole company data is very expensive because it has to retrieve around 60k result. By giving the batch size 1000 it has to do a round trip around 60 times to ES to get all the results in the memory. It's time and space consuming both.

Can somebody please suggest a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve it using [filtered aggregations:](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) with [top hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)

As an example you can do something like:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "filtered_companies_by_us": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "location": "US"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_companies": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "overallRank": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 5
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @jordivador, Thanks for the reply. I could not work on this requirement in last few days. I will try this today and let you know if this works for me.

Comment: So I was trying to understand the top_hits and I believe it's not going to solve my issue.
It will give me the top N hits per bucket. For example, I can get top 5 hits for US location by top_hits and can get filtered result with the filter query. So let say my filter is giving me compan1, company3, company4, company5, and top_hits is giving me company2, company4,... so I can determine the sort order of  my company in the filter result if that present in the top_hits but what if the company does not belong to top n hits of top_hits. how can I determine the order of that company?

Comment: Well, if you need all of your indexed companies ranking, you will need to paginate through top_hits aggregation, this feature was discussed years ago and seems that will be available (if not it's right now) to ES 6.2.x . https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/pull/1399